# How to make terminator transparent?

Tags: terminator

I'm using a standard installation of Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity and I'd like to make terminator transparent as we can easily do for the standard terminal.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Right click anywhere in the terminator window and choose "Preferences", your desired option should be found under "Profiles"->Background":

[image]

Comment: ... I hadn't even found terminator preferences... I wasn't imagining there even was a GUI... Thanks !

Comment: this way you get a composite transparent terminal (shows desktop), Is there some way to enable regular transparent terminal?

Answer (score 10):

Edit your config file in $HOME like this (i.e. vi) :

```
vi $HOME/.config/terminator/config
```

insert into [profiles] [[default]] the transparency settings:

```
background_darkness = 0.97 #(or anything else between 0-1)
background_type = transparent
```

this works for me.

Comment: This I think is a better method as it can simply be copied.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on terminator screen

[image]

1. Click on **Preferences**
2. Click on **Profiles** tab
3. Under Profiles click on **Background** tab
4. Check **Transparent background**
5. Set the transparency (Optional)

[image]

Comment: This answer looks a little like a duplicate, doesn't it ?